# SQL Server trusted connection additional security

Tags: sql-server, security, sql-server-2017, connectivity

Using Windows authentication, is there a way to prohibit users from connecting via ODBC to the database?

Comment: Do you want to restrict ODBC connection to a certain database or the entire SQL instance?

Comment: both solution can work

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The feature designed to help in this scenario is [Application Roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/application-roles?view=sql-server-ver15).  With an Application Role you can allow the user to connect to the target database, but not be able to run any queries until the application supplies a secret to activate the Application Role.

Comment: I can never decide if this is SQL Server's *worst marketed* or *best kept secret* feature.  LOL!

Comment: It’s not perfect, At least for desktop applications, as a user with a debugger can discover the Application Role secret.

Comment: I have been using sql for several years. 
Incredibly I had never taken into consideration this feature. Thank you!

Comment: "as a user with a debugger can discover the Application Role secret"-> to solve this problem i'm planning to set app role in custom stored procedure, based on current user, at application startup so only dba can view the definition.

Answer (score 7):

A *possible* solution is to create a server logon trigger that would check the `app_name()`.  I created the following server trigger on my local instance and tried to connect via ODBC. The connection was rejected.  You would have to modify for your needs.

```
CREATE TRIGGER trgGetAppName ON ALL SERVER
FOR LOGON AS

IF APP_NAME() NOT LIKE ('Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio%')
    AND APP_NAME() NOT LIKE ('.Net SqlClient Data Provider%')
BEGIN
    ROLLBACK
END
```

---

**A word of caution about logon triggers:**

> A logon trigger can effectively prevent successful connections to the
>   Database Engine for all users, including members of the sysadmin fixed
>   server role. When a logon trigger is preventing connections, members
>   of the sysadmin fixed server role can connect by using the dedicated
>   administrator connection, or by starting the Database Engine in
>   minimal configuration mode (-f)

Comment: Logon triggers can be [bypassed with the proper effort](https://blog.netspi.com/bypass-sql-logon-triggers/), but perhaps a login trigger in conjunction with a lookup against the [`sys.dm_exec_connections`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-connections-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) (specifically looking at the `client_interface_name` column for `ODBC` connections) would do the trick for most scenarios.

Comment: @JohnEisbrener - Thanks for the comments!

Comment: You are aware that the app name can be modified client-side right? This is absolutely not secure.